# scale the size of analytic region obtained form PolyhedronData

Tags: regions, polyhedra

I would like to know if it is possible to find the equation of the internal region of a polygon, whose size has been rescaled.

For example:

The analytic region for a Dodecahedron is founded of:

```
PolyhedronData ["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"] [x, y, z]
```

if I plot the equation of dodecahedron:

```
With [{r = 5}, RegionPlot3D [PolyhedronData ["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"] [x, y, z], {x, -r,r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 20, Mesh -> None]]
```

I would like to be able to modify the size of the Dodecahedron, so that it can be contained in a box of size 1 or 2. Something similar to ScalingTransform [{1, 1, 1}], but to applied to an analytic expression.

Comment: As I commented in your other (deleted) question, the scaling factor you need is `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Circumradius"]`. Divide the variables with this factor, and you get the polyhedron inscribed in a sphere of radius $1$.

Comment: but does not work,  With[{r = 1}, 
 RegionPlot3D[
  Apply[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"], {x, y, z}/
    PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Circumradius"]], {x, -r, 
   r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}, PlotPoints -> 10]].  The size of the resulting Dodecahedron is greater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Working with the function `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"]` and using `ScalingTransform`:

```
 regFunc = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"]
```

To scale the graphics object with `ScalingTransform[{s1,s2,s3}]` we can scale the `{x,y,z}` coordinates passed to `regFunc` with `{1/s1, 1/s2, 1/s3}` (that is, use `regFunc[x/s1, y/s2, z/s3]`)

```
rp3Da = RegionPlot3D[regFunc[x, y, z], 
   {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
   PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.2, Blue], Opacity[.2, Blue]], 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"];

rp3Db = RegionPlot3D[regFunc[2 x, 2 y, 2 z]], 
   {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 50,
   Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[rp3Da, rp3Db]
```

[image]

Compare the `rp3Db` with the result of using `ScalingTransform[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}]` on `rp3Da`:

```
rp3Dc = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ScalingTransform[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}]] &, 
   rp3Da, {1}];

Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {rp3Db, rp3Dc}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ir = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "ImplicitRegion"];

rgnbnds = RegionBounds[N @ ir]
```

> ```
> {{-1.37638, 1.37638}, {-1.30902, 1.30902}, {-1.11352, 1.11352}}
> ```

You can use [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) to get the region function:

```
rF = RegionMember[ir];
```

This is same as the function obtained using `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"]`:

```
Resolve @ ForAll[{x, y, z}, Element[{x, y, z}, Reals], 
  Equivalent[rF[{x, y, z}], PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z]]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
rp3d = RegionPlot3D[ir, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

#### [`GeometricTransformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) + [`RescalingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RescalingTransform.html)

**1.** rescale to unit cube:

```
MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RescalingTransform[rgnbnds]] &, rp3d, {1}]
```

[image]

**2.** rescale to `Cuboid[{-.5, -.5, -.5}, {.5, .5, .5}]`:

```
MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RescalingTransform[rgnbnds, {#, #, #}&@{-.5, .5}]] &,
    rp3d, {1}]
```

[image]

#### [`ScalingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingTransform.html):

```
MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ScalingTransform[{.5, .5, 1}]] &, rp3d, {1}]
```

[image]

#### [`TransformedRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html)

Alternatively, we can use [`TransformedRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html) with a tranformation of our choice to transformed the region object. For example,

```
tr = TransformedRegion[ir, ScalingTransform[{.5, .5, 1}]];

RegionPlot3D[tr, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

#### [`RegionResize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionResize.html)

Resize `ir` to have *"resize the region reg to have the first side length 1 preserving side length ratios"*:

```
resized = RegionResize[N @ ir, 1];

RegionPlot3D[resized, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

You can get a region function for the transformed or resized region using `RegionMember`. For example,

```
RegionMember[resized][{x, y, z}]
```

> ```
>  (x | y | z) ∈ \[DoubleStruckCapitalR] && -46.8328 x - 
>    23.4164 z <= 21.1803 && 46.8328 x + 23.4164 z <= 21.1803 && 
>  14.4721 x - 44.5407 y + 23.4164 z <= 21.1803 && 10.4721 z <= 4.23607 && 
>  14.4721 x + 44.5407 y + 23.4164 z <= 21.1803 && 
>  37.8885 x + 27.5276 y - 23.4164 z <= 21.1803 && 
>  37.8885 x - 27.5276 y - 23.4164 z <= 21.1803 && 
>  -14.4721 x + 44.5407 y - 23.4164 z <= 21.1803 && 
>  -2.75276 z <= 1.11352 && -14.4721 x - 44.5407 y - 23.4164 z <= 21.1803 &&
>  -37.8885 x - 27.5276 y + 23.4164 z <=  21.1803 &&
>   -37.8885 x + 27.5276 y + 23.4164 z <= 21.1803
> ```

Comment: Thank, but I would like to obtain the analytic expression of inner region of a re-scale  polygon, similar to PolyhedronData ["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"] [x, y, z]

Comment: @F.Mark, I added some notes on how you can use `RegionMember` to get the desired region functions.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @F.Mark, you are most welcome. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Thank you for everything, do you also know if that figure can be rotated around an axis?

Comment: @F.Mark, try if `angle=Pi/2;xaxis={1,0,0}; rot = TransformedRegion[N@ir, RotationTransform[angle, xaxis]];
RegionPlot3D[{ir, rot}, PlotPoints -> 40]` helps. If not, please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much, one last question, when it takes you time to run RegionMember[resized][{x, y, z}]? more than 10 min?

Comment: @F.Mark, using `resized = RegionResize[N@ir, 1]; 
RegionMember[resized][{x, y, z}] // AbsoluteTiming // First` I get
`0.0060059`. If I use `ir` instead of `N@ir` , `RegionMember[resized][{x, y, z}] // AbsoluteTiming` gives `18.332` along with many error messages/warnings (Version 11.3 Windows10).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106919/discussion-between-f-mark-and-kglr).